# Azure Service bus trigger for function app with session enabled - Node.js

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have a function that is trigged by service bus with session enabled, but I get the error:

```
Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus: It is not possible for an entity that requires sessions to create a non-sessionful message receiver
```

Is there a way to enable sessions with nodejs app?

I tried to edit my host.json but it didnt work, SessionHandlerOptions is not showing as property for serviceBus... "Property SessionHandlerOptions is not allowed"

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "SessionHandlerOptions": ....

      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Also tried to add `"isSessionsEnabled": true` in function.json but still getting same error.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after some hours and thanks to the suggestion from @BowmanZhu I found the solution that works also when using node.js. 
Im using azure-functions-core-tools, so update it to latest version:

```
npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools@2
```

From the root map of the project install the package 3.1.1 of ServiceBus extension:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus --version 3.1.1
```

In the `extensions.csproj` file you should see now that the package reference for the package is 3.1.1

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="3.1.1" />
```

then run:

```
func extensions install
```

last add in function.json add in bindings:

```
"isSessionsEnabled": true
```

run `func start` to start the function app locally. You should not see anymore the error message and a queue with session enabled can be used to trig the function.

Comment: Can you mark my answer if my answer is helpful to you?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I think the right answer to mark(which is going to help other people with same problem) is this one.

Comment: Ok, it doesn't matter. Thank you for your contribution of community.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common question. Azure Functions don't support Service Bus sessions since Azure Function was create. This situation keeps for 3-4 years. Several months ago comes up a nuget package to Support this. For `node.js` I don't find a SDK to install. If you use `C#`, now it has a solution. But for `node.js`, I am not sure. You can have a try of the newest SDK, maybe it can support this.

This is an Function [SDK issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-servicebus-extension/issues/16). You can take a look.